# How to show decimals for distance (i.e. 1.5m) in Legend Item Name on QGIS

Tags: qgis, legend

I have created my map but my Legend Items Labels are not showing the indicated distance in meters with decimals typed in. the legend item cuts off and begins a new line. For instance, I have a legend item that is "Trail width - 1.5m". In my Legend, they are appearing as follows:

Trail width - 1 (then the .5m drops to the next line, so it is separate from the 1)
5m

when it should show: Trail width - 1.5m

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does **Wrap text on** option in **Main Properties** of the Legend has a value? [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG25Y.png)

Comment: Thank you Kadir! Wrap text on  option was set to "." I have removed the decimal and left that space blank. That worked. I am new to QGIS and learning as I go. Thank you again.